# Change document-root on Shared-host?

Tags: zend-framework, shared-hosting, document-root

When you deploy a Zend Framework website to a shared host, you usually cannot change the DocumentRoot to point at the public/ folder of the website. As a result the URL to the website is now http://www.example.com/public/.

Apart from choosing a proper host..there's any workaround?

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to directories above public, you can put all non public files there. 
Otherwise, you can put everything in a subdirectory, and block access to it with an `.htaccess` file.

Comment: there's no way to take off that "/public" from the url?

Comment: @luca There is, just put the contents of the "public" folder in your "public_html", "htdocs" or equivalent folder, and put the Zend Framework files in the directory just above it.

Comment: I have an issue.For testing I put everything in a subfolder 'mysite.com/zend'(I have another project on the root)..and put the content of the 'public' folder directly inside the 'zend' one.The point is my complete url for a page is: mysite.com/zend/index/index..and the front controller considers zend as an url parameter! so I changed the route in my bootstrap to this:   $router->addRoute('lang',new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('zend/:lang/:controller/:action',
 array('lang'=>':lang',
 'module'=>'default',
 'controller'=>'index',
 'action'=>'index')));

Comment: but i receive an exception :'no route matched the request'..where is the problem?

Comment: it doesn't make sense that zend is considered a url parameter...what does your .htaccess file look like?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/favicon.ico$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /zend/index.php [NC,L]

Comment: Sorry solved..I thought I had to modify the route!just removed the 'zend' from the route =) thanks again